# Lazy load a view from xml

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, android-canvas, lazy-loading

I am working with a huge xml file(1.3 mb) from server, it takes about 25 seconds to download from server.

I am getting coordinates from the server. I have to draw them on the screen, so is there a way I can *lazy load the view*?

I am able to download the xml file and store it in the internal memory and parse it using the SAX parser.

Also can I download the xml in chunks and parse them as I go on?

To Elaborate my problem,

**1.** I need to download and parse an xml file from the server. The file is roughly 1.3 MB

**2.** It takes about 30 seconds to download and 4 seconds to parse.

**3.** I am storing it in a local file and parsing it using SAX parser.

**4.** In this xml file I am getting the drawing points from which I recreate a drawing on a canvas.

So is there any way I can work on the drawing part as the xml file is being downloaded and parsed on the chunk of downloaded file to minimize the delay and parse smaller segments from the server?

Comment: You may want to split your file into serveral parts , each part contains description to draw an area , then you go.

Comment: can you post some code on how to do this.

Comment: It's just an idea to implement on server, like you have 1.3 MB which will take you 30 secs to download , now you split it into 3 files with 0.4 MB and 1 file with 0.1 MB (make the total = 1.3 MB).
Each of these files has contain to describe information enough for you to draw a part of your view.

You have seperate thread to do network communication, and the main thread (  UI thread ) to draw what you get from network thread.
That's just an idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of view/data you're talking about (`MapView`?) but you have to show *something* while the download and parse operation takes place.

The [Android design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html) suggests showing a centered `ProgressBar`, which they refer to as an "Activity circle". After the operation is complete, hide the progress bar and show your view instead (use a `FrameLayout` to overlap the "waiting" and "ready" views so you can easily switch between them by changing the visibility).

> In this example, an activity circle (in Holo Light) is used in the
>   Gmail application when a message is being loaded because it's not
>   possible to determine how long it will take to download the email.
>
> When displaying an activity circle, do not include text to communicate
>   what the app is doing. The moving circle alone provides sufficient
>   feedback about the delay, and does so in an understated way that
>   minimizes the impact.

[image: activity circle]

Comment: this is not what I want exactly I am displaying this progress dialog it's just that I want to optimise the downloading of this huge xml file

Comment: @AashishBhatnagar Ah, in that case you need to feed the stream you get from the download directly to the SAX parser so you can parse as the data arrives.

Comment: tried that still taking 18 seconds I even tried stax but no use I guess we can never achieve the xml performace as in case of actionscript

Comment: @AashishBhatnagar The download time is a function of the file size **and** the user's connection. No matter how fast you're able to use the data, the entire process is always going to take *at least* as long as the download time. The only sure way to guarantee faster downloads is to download less (refresh the data less frequently, only fetch changes instead of the entire dataset, etc.).